# How to create a video in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm not good at English.

I want to create a music video using picture,music and movie in local.
I see `AVFoundation` api and `UIImage` array to video'
then, I capture scene in `spriteKit` and create `NSArray`, but, I think it has an error about memory.
so, **It can render 30sec. but it can't render 60sec.**

I can't find any source.
Please give me a hint!

Comment: Without out code it not possible to tell you exact reason behind it. Share your code what ever your tried so far.

Comment: What you need is AVAssetExportSession. Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH8-SW1.

Comment: @Anonymous sure but, I want make like this(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xQdUwsaBRo) but my code is capture and add to NSArray and use 'UIImage array to video' function.